# Series whose terms are logs of rational functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the value of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \frac{n^2+2n}{(n+1)^2}.
$$

The professor said it telescopes, but after I do partial fractions on the part inside the log, I don't know how to proceed, since the log gets in the way.  Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you considered separating the logarithm into parts so that the $n^{th}$ term looks like $$\log(n^2+2n)-\log((n+1)^2)$$

Comment: Continuing with @TerraHyde , you can use log rules to get $\log(n)+\log(n+2)-2\log(n+1)$, which will telescope nicely.

Comment: Oh, now I see! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log \frac{n^2+2n}{(n+1)^2} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log\left( n(n+2)) \right) - \log \left( n+1 \right)^2 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \log n + \log(n+2) - 2\log(n+1) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\left( \log(n+2) - \log(n+1) \right) - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left( \log(n+1) - \log n\right)
$$

And that's how it telescopes.